# How to create .list file in C#

Tags: c#, string, text, io

I know how to put string list to a .txt file for example:

```
//nw_TCList is a string list

string nwFinal = String.Join("\n", nw_TCList.ToArray());
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(nwPath, nwFinal);
```

So my question is how to put this string list file to a .list file?

-------------Question update

Thank you for all the reply, nwPath is my txt file address. (@"c:\abc\name.txt")

Problem solved! just change .txt to .list, LOL, i was thinking how to convert txt file to list file before, haha.

Comment: Write it to a .txt file but change the .txt to .list?

Comment: What is the value of `nwPath` ? adding `.list` to that string it will solve your issues

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Strings.list", Strings_array)` does the job

Comment: @waka, I want to write it directly to a .list file

Comment: @ZeZhang: That what I said. Instead of setting the extension to `.txt` in your program, just set it to `.list`.

Comment: @qjnr, thanks qjnr! problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.list is just Extension so don't worry about that

there is direct method to write Array to file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(nwPath, nw_TCList);
```

And If you want to have .list Extension
give that in path param
E.g.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("D://Data.list", nw_TCList);
```

that did trick for me

Comment: Thanks, it makes the code more beautiful. But it is still .txt file if I just want .list file as an output file type, how to do that?

Comment: Please check my new Updated Answer @ZeZhang

Comment: Thanks a lot : )

Comment: @ZeZhang please Upvote and accept answer if it was helpful